# python dockerpy token issues running docker with jupyter notebook

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook, devops, dockerpy

I am using dockerpy to create a docker, And trying to run a docker with an operating jupyter notbook using [this](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks)

I run this command from the terminal

```sh
docker run -p 8888:8888 jupyter/scipy-notebook:17aba6048f44
```

And get the jupyter notebook running, I get the login token in the terminal, and able to connect to is beautifully via port 8888

When I try to use this code in python using dockerpy

```py
conda_jupyter = "jupyter/scipy-notebook:17aba6048f44"
cont = self.client.containers.create(conda_jupyter,
                                                 ports={"8888/tcp": "8887"})
log = h.client.containers.run(conda_jupyter, stdout=True, detach=True)
print(log.logs())
```

I get the following output

> b'Container must be run with group "root" to update passwd
>   file\nExecuting the command: jupyter notebook\n'

The docker is now alive, the jupyter notebook is running, and i don't have the token to log into it. How can I get the token when running it from this command?

I do not assume the output has anything to do with the problem, given that the process is running, and when i ran it from the terminal, I did not use any sudo or root, and did not change any password, the only thing I needed was the token output from the terminal and this is what i need now.

What am i missing here?

Thanks